# Mpmovieplayerviewcontroller, how to check broken link

Tags: ios4

I am new to iphone.
I write the app to play video. I use MpMovieplayerviewcontroller to play video stream
but when i play with broken url or when don't have internet, app stop suddenly.

so i want to ask there is the way to check url or internet connection to alert before player stop.
Thanks for your help.
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check apple's reachability class ? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html Download sample code from there !!